# Set env variable from BASH script

Tags: bash, variables, env

I need make something like

```
$ source /etc/environments # called in bash.sh script
```

Of course after script finished no changes apply to shell.
I know this is tricky if because child process cant modify parent 'bash' process. But May be another way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
source bash.sh
```

Then it runs in the original shell instead of a child process.

Answer (score 1):

As you have observed yourself a child process cannot set persistent environment variables. One of the usual work around are writing something like this to stdout:

```
% cat my_script
#!/bin/bash
echo "export MY_VAR=1234"
```

And then used in a command substitution:

```
eval "$(./my_script)"
```

An example of such script is `dircolors`

Comment: @123 It will work with bash scripts, but nothing else.

Comment: I ment that `my_script` needs to be written in the same language as where it's sourced, and no `$(...)` is not bash only.

Comment: I meant not portable,not just bash, sorry. But this still doesn't make any sense to do,

Comment: @123 OP asks for a way for a child process to set environment variables in the parent shell. I assume he want a general solution that also works when the child process is machine code, perl, python, ... Unless you can show me a way to source a python script, I will hold at this method.

Comment: What i meant is, I can't see a reason to use an external process to set variables in the current shell. You can run python et al. inside a sourced script and have them output the values you want anyway.

Comment: @123 And how should that Python program return the variables that should be added in the sourced shell...?

Comment: print/echo them. `IFS=$'\n'
export vars=($(python -c 'print "1\n2 3\n4"'))` or don't export the array and assign the array elements to exported vars as needed in the sourced script.